# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is hanging

Tags: boot, 18.04, browser

Ubuntu 18.04 is hanging a lot in my PC. I recently installed a fresh copy of it from the official website but it is working like hell.

It takes over 2 minutes to boot up and after that the browsers are hanging a lot (Chromium & Firefox).

I am on a dell machine (Dell 14R N4110)
Specs are as follows

HDD CAPACITY- 500GB
RAM- 4GB
CPU- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2370M CPU @ 2.40GHz with 4 processors

Any help will be highly appreciated
THANX IN ADVANCE

Comment: There are already many my-boot-is-slow questions here - have you looked at those? Your RAM seems a bit low for modern 64-bit usage. Have you tried a lower-resource desktop like Lubuntu or Xubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to go back to 16.04.  This 18.04 distribution appears to be a mess on many fronts.